# Matplotlib heatmap using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to produce a heatmap using matplolib and this `pandas` dataframe:

```
          class  time  day
0         URxvt     2    6
1         Emacs     3    6
2       Firefox    90    6
3     KeePassXC     5    6
4         URxvt    91    6
..          ...   ...  ...
144  Matplotlib     1    1
145  Matplotlib     1    1
146  Matplotlib     2    1
147  Matplotlib     5    1
148  Matplotlib    93    1

[149 rows x 3 columns]
```

I want to produce a heatmap with day (from 0 to 6 (but for the moment 0, 1 and 6)) on x-axis and class on y-axis, values are aggregate sums according to class and day).
I tried to `groupby` these two columns which produces:

```
                          time
class               day       
Emacs               0     1149
                    1      130
                    6      634
Eog                 1       83
                    6       66
Evince              0      775
                    6       60
File-roller         0       40
Firefox             0    32109
                    1     6344
                    6     9887
GParted             1       25
Gedit               0       77
                    1        7
Gimp-2.10           6       25
Gmpc                1       73
Gnome-disks         1       21
Gtk-recordmydesktop 0       57
Gufw.py             6      100
KeePassXC           0       44
                    1       17
                    6      126
Matplotlib          1      151
Org.gnome.Nautilus  0      141
                    1      559
                    6       68
Scangearmp2         6       28
Totem               0       12
URxvt               0      346
                    1      488
                    6     3364
vlc                 0       22
```

but I can't get a proper heatmap (with X:day Y:class and values: time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
sns.heatmap(df.groupby(['class','day'])['time'].sum()
              .unstack('day',fill_value=0)
           )
```

Output:

[image]